# Moodle : How to insert Real Life data?

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

I have Moodle 2.9 version up and running.

I need the way to insert Real Life data into Moodle? For e.g 100 Courses with 1000 Users. Each user in Random 5-10 Courses. Courses having different resources like audio, video, files. etc.

I have tried PHP tools like:

1. maketestcourse.php [for creating courses]
2. maketestplan.php [for creating jmeter script for courses]

The problem with maketestcourse.php is:

1. It generates courses with resources [pages, forums etc], but the resource are empty. Resources are created empty.

Can anyone please point me to moodle API, that can be used to generate data into moodle and there sequence of use? OR
Any dummy Moodle dump with Real Life data?

Thanks!

Comment: maketestcourse.php and other tools are in location: /admin/tool/generator/cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Moosh but you will need to create the list of commands for your test site.

http://moosh-online.com/commands/